# add css to iframe javascript form list of iframes

Tags: javascript, css, iframe

I am trying to manipulate an iframe (chatbox) when loaded on a webpage.
The chatbox loads four iframes with changing id with each pageload.
Because the iframe that needs to be manipulated is the last / 4th of the list, i used get elements by tagname ("iframe").

However, no style is added to the last iframe:

```
<script> 
window.onload = function() {
   let myiFrame = document.getElementsByTagName("iframe");
   let doc = myiFrame[3].contentDocument;
   doc.body.innerHTML = doc.body.innerHTML + "<style>iframe{dispay:block !important}</style>";
   
    }</script>
```

Comment: What do you mean by "doesnt seem to be working"?

Comment: You are right. No style is added to the last (fourth) iframe...

Comment: If you want to format the `iframe` element itself - then why are you injecting styles into the document that is loaded _inside_ the iframe? The iframe _element_ itself, is part of the “parent” document.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use

```
myiFrame[3].style.cssText = "display:block !important"
```

your code will become

```
<script> 
window.onload = function() {
   let myiFrame = document.getElementsByTagName("iframe");
   myiFrame[3].style.cssText = "display:block !important";
   }
</script>
```

Sample working code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<p id="myP1" style="display: none!important">This is some text.</p>

<input type="button" onclick="demoDisplay()" value="Show">

<script>
function demoDisplay() {
  document.getElementById("myP1").style.cssText = "display:block !important";
}

</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: No sorry doesnt work... Maybe is it because the iframe has display:none !important as attribute when loaded?

Comment: Updated my answer. style.cssText works even when display: none !important

Comment: May be you need to use document.ready instead of window.onload

Comment: You were right, my bet... i miscounted the amounts of iframes. I needed the last = 5, so myiFrame[5]. now it is working.